# Permanently storing zsh aliases

Tags: command-line, zsh

I created a new alias by typing:

```
~ alias gpo='git push origin'
```

I see my newly created alias when I type `alias` (which lists all the available aliases) but when I close my terminal and reopen it, they vanish.

- How do I ensure that it is permanently available?
- How do I keep a backup of all my aliases so I can carry them with me even if I move between computers?

Comment: @RomanTsegelskyi Where does the .zshrc go?

Comment: P.S. You might want to consided closing this question, until it gets marked as duplicate since there are many other questions about aliases

Comment: You could also store them in a separate file (which you can move between computers) and source that from .zshrc.  You can save your aliases to that file using "alias -L > ~/.zsh_aliases". I always add an alias for that, so I can create and save aliases directly from the command line,

Answer (score 11):

You can keep it inside ~/.zshrc